# Access single file in multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am trying to write trace(text file) for my application having multiple threads. Want to know whether it is possible or not. My application is written in VB.Net.

Any help would be appreciated! TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to the same file at the same time as the file will be locked, you would encounter version problems anyway.

What you would be better doing is creating a single sub that deals with the update of this file and would queue tasks to update it. Although without more information on what you are wanting to accomplish it is difficult to tell. Why are you wanting to use this approach? There may be a better way of going about it.

Comment: I am trying to update trace file in case any error occurs while thread is active. Thanks :)

Comment: In which case I'd use the approach I suggested above to log errors to a file. Have a central function that deals with writing to this file instead of trying to write to the same file from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Use file locking:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

```
MyFileClass myFile


lock(myFile)
  {
      // Write to file in here.
  }
```